# How to plot a bar chart if the input data is of type list?

Tags: python, list, pandas, collections

```
result = collections.Counter(words).most_common(3)

print result
```

The result is:

```
[('want', 3), ('dtype', 1), ('object', 1)]
```

Now I want to plot a histogram with the selected 3 words. How can I do this? The following way does not work.

```
plt.hist(result,histtype='bar')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use value_counts (of a Series) this will plot:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series("want want want dtype object".split())

In [12]: s.value_counts()
Out[12]:
want      3
object    1
dtype     1
dtype: int64
```

which you can then [plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#histograms):

```
In [13]: s.value_counts().plot(kind='hist')
```

---

To get the Series from the Counter you could use zip:

```
In [21]: words, counts = zip(*[('want', 3), ('dtype', 1), ('object', 1)])

In [22]: pd.Series(counts, words)
Out[22]:
want      3
dtype     1
object    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Why 'hist' instead of 'bar'?